# How to create icicles hanging off an object?

Tags: modeling, workflow

Is there a way to create icicles,
for example like this:

[image]

I was thinking if there was some way to use a *Snake Hook* brush on many random places at once with different strengths etc., but I don't know if this is possible.

How can I achieve this?

---

Image from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Icicles_forming.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Icicle Generator

This addon creates rows of very realistic icicles along all selected edges of an object. You can [download and read about it here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?331186-Add-On-Snowflake-and-Icicle-generator).

Here is an example of how beautifully they render:

[image]

To enable Icicle Generator:

1. Download the addon by [clicking here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90158352/KEEP%20-%20Blender/Addons/SnowflakeIcicleGenerators.zip).
2. Open the User Preferences:
   *Info* header → *File* → *User Preferences*

   [image]
3. Click on *Addons* at the top of the Preferences window, and then click on the *Install from File* button at the bottom of the window:

   [image]
4. Next:

   - Find the addon file and select it (the file can be a `.zip` file -- you don't have to unzip it first)
   - Click the *Install from File* button
   - Then enable it by clicking the checkbox on the far right of the addon
   - If you want Icicle Generator to be enabled by default in the future, click on the *Save User Settings* button:

   [image]
5. To add icicles to an object, the object must be a mesh. If it is a curve object, simply convert it to a mesh object with <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> → *Convert to Mesh*
6. Go into *Edit* mode, select all edges you'd like to have icicles hanging from, make a copy of those edges and make them a separate object:
   <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>  → <kbd>ENTER</kbd> →  <kbd>P</kbd> → *Separate Selection*

   [image]

   This will create a new mesh object composed only of the edges where you want icicles to be. 
   **NOTE:** Don't move this icicle edge object -- it's in just the correct place now.
7. You **MUST** apply the icicle edge object's *Location*, *Rotation* and *Scale* while in Object mode before adding the icicles:
   *Object* mode → select object → <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> → *Location* → <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> → *Rotation & Scale*
8. Now select the newly created edge object, go into Edit mode, select all, and add the icicles:
   Select edge object → <kbd>TAB</kbd> → select All (<kbd>A</kbd>) → <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> → *Icicle*

   [image]
9. To adjust the settings, open the *Tools* panel (<kbd>T</kbd>):

   [image]

   These settings (above) yield icicles like this:

   [image]

   However, if you want a more random appearance, set the *Min D* to 0.2 and *Min R* to 0.01 -- this causes some icicles to be so small they appear to not be there, yielding icicles like this:

   [image]

   **NOTE:** You **MUST** set all the settings the way you want them to be before you do **ANYTHING** else, otherwise they cannot be changed again.
10. Now rename the newly created icicles object to "Icicles" and assign them a Glass material:

    [image]
11. If you want to, you can give the icicles a [bump texture](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Textures/Influence/Material/Bump_and_Normal).

Answer (score 4):

You could use a Particle System of type `Hair`.

Make a plane and apply a particle system to it.

Also make an icicle as a separate object, or make several and make a group out of them.
Remember to set the origin of each icicle to where it should start growing on the plain, and also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> apply rotation&scale.

In the particle system properties, go to `Render`. If you made just one icicle, choose the `Object` tab and your icicle as `Dupli Object`. If you made several, go to `Group` tab and choose your group.

Then play with settings in particle system to get correct rotations, placements and scale. Randomness can be applied to all.

Here's a quick result with only one icicle object (open image in new tab to see full size):

[image]
[image]

Edit:

If you want to fine-tune location of icicles, set `Particles/Face = 1` and edit the faces on the plane to exactly where each icicle should originate. Remember to set matching count to amount of faces.