# How can I make unique rocks in Blender without having to model them by hand?

Tags: modeling

How can I make unique rocks in Blender without having to model them by hand? I've tried making them by hand, but often they don't look as realistic as I'd like.

Plus, sometimes I'd like to have LOTS of them but don't want to spend the time modeling them all. Is there an easy solution?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Add Rocks

The [Add Rocks](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Rock_Generator) addon allows you to quickly add randomly generated mesh rocks, thus making it much quicker to add detail & realism to your outdoor settings. Here you can [read about](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Rock_Generator) this addon.

Here are some examples of the presets and some variations:

[image]

To enable this addon:

1. Download it from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c2d9sgq9n0xyg3z/add_mesh_rocks.zip).
2. Now open User Preferences:
   *Info* header  →  *File*  →  *User Preferences*

   [image]
3. Click on *Addons* at the top of the Preferences window, and then click on the *Install from File* button at the bottom of the window:

   [image]
4. Next:

   - Find the addon file and select it. (**NOTE:** The file can be a `.zip` file -- you don't have to unzip it first.)
   - Click the *Install from File* button
   - Then enable the addon by clicking on it's checkbox on the far right
   - If you want this addon to be enabled by default in the future, click on the *Save User Settings* button:

   [image]
5. To add a rock to your scene:
   <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> -> Mesh -> Rock Generator

   [image]
6. Adjust all the settings:

   [image]

   One very neat feature is that you can make as many rocks as you want all at once, ***each one unique***, by setting the Number of Rocks at the top -- here I'm making 500 all at once:

   [image]

   Notice at the very bottom, there are some presets:

   [image]

   **NOTE:** You **MUST** set all the settings the way you want them to be before you do **ANYTHING** else, otherwise they cannot be changed through the same settings panel. After you click away from the rocks, you can only modify their parameters via the modifiers that are on them:
   *Object Properties* panel -> *Modifiers* tab

### Apply All Modifiers BEFORE Rendering

One thing to be careful of is that each rock created has many modifiers on it and these **DRAMATICALLY** slow down rendering speed! So, to get around this, you really need to Apply all modifiers **BEFORE** attempting to render your scene. To do this you can do either of the following:

1. **Manually Apply Modifiers:**  This is an easy method, but it can take a lot of time if you have more than 1 rock:
   Select rock -> Object Properties panel -> Modifiers tab -> click the Apply button on the modifier

   [image]
2. **Convert All Rocks to Mesh:** This is the best and quickest method if you don't want to sit around clicking "Apply" for a long time:
   Select ALL the rocks at once -> <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> -> Convert to Mesh

   This will very easily Apply **ALL** the modifiers without you having to do anything else and you can now render quickly and easily:

   [image]

Comment: What version of blender and the addon are you using? I could not get it to work on 2.7 and a few 2.6x versions I tried.

Comment: It works fine for me in 2.69 and 2.70a. What problems are you encountering?

Comment: @David I just updated my answer to clarify how to install the addon & made it much easier to install. See if that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is also a *Rock Generator* add-on that comes with Blender v2.79 and higher. You can check this box in the Blender Preferences: Add-ons: Objects: Rock Generator.