# where is the blender rock generator addon?

Tags: modeling

Here's the tut:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJRDj-fwkG4&t=508s

The reason why I'm asking is, that there seem to be many different rock generators, all the links I've found on the web point to other rock generators (such as [here](https://github.com/Bombaba/BlenderPythonScripts/blob/master/add_mesh_lowpoly_rock.py)) and were wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the add-on from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c2d9sgq9n0xyg3z/add_mesh_rocks.zip): use the "Download > Direct Download" button that will create a `.zip` file.

You will be able to install the add-on from *File > User Preferences > Add-ons*, using "Install from File" and selecting the zip file. You don't have to unzip it!

I haven't extensively tested it, but the basic features seem to work on Blender 2.79b on Ubuntu (even if the file is much older).

More in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8747) by Thom Blair III. I don't know who maintains the Dropbox link above.

Answer (score 3):

The rock generator is part of the "Testing" Add-on category, and thus not installed if you use the official Blender install package. You can find the repository with all the experimental add-ons here:

https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/repository/master/

Sadly, the repository viewer doesn't support direct downloads, so you need Git to clone it locally. Or use [this GitHub mirror](https://github.com/sobotka/blender-addons-contrib) instead. Extract the contents into `<Blender install path>/<version>/scripts/addons_contrib`, restart Blender and enable the "Testing" category in the add-on manager.

Answer (score 1):

It's now an official addon in 3.x. Go to Blender Preferences > Addons, then search for 'Add Mesh > Extra Objects'.