How should I go about turning a 2D image of a rock face into a 3D model
I have a photo of small section of a rock face that I wish to turn into a 3D model so that I can 3D print it. The dimensions and etc do not need to be exact as I am aware that I do not have a 3D scan, I just want a good well textured accurate looking model to print.
So far I have imported the image to blender and used the knife and extrude tool to start creating a shape, but I do not know how to progress from here.
I imagine I should add some sort of texture, because I want to have a textured realistic looking model that I can print.


Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see How to take a screenshot. Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

"So far I have imported the image to blender and used the knife and extrude tool to start creating a shape" This doesn't seem helpful for what you want to achieve. Please see existing techniques for modelling organic shapes: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26869/what-techniques-are-used-to-begin-creating-new-models/26881#26881 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8746/how-can-i-make-unique-rocks-in-blender-without-having-to-model-them-by-hand/8747#8747
