# making extrude edges follow face normals

Tags: modeling, mesh, normals

Is it possible to make extrude edges act like when you extrude a face by default in Blender? (following the face normal)

[image]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8782/how-do-i-extrude-perpendicular-to-a-plane-not-oriented-along-x-y-or-z. Also in many cases you should be able to extrude them after switching Transform Orientation to *Normal*.

Comment: Hmm that does not produce the result i am after. I just realized that if you choose "local" and then pres e + zz i get the result i am after. Maybe it's possible to write a script for this so that i don't have to do this everytime?

Comment: The *Local* mode worked for you most likely because the model was rotated while in Object mode so local coordinates were saved. It may be a little bit tricky to select between transform orientations needed, so the easiest way may be to fill the temporar face as in the link provided.