# Is there a way to procedurally scatter objects on the ground of my scene?

Tags: modeling, particles, instances

I would like to have plants, rocks, sticks and other debris scattered randomly on the ground in my scene, but I don't want to have to place it all there by hand. Is there an easy way to do this in Blender?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Placing Objects Randomly on the Ground with a Hair Particle System

Using a [Hair Particle system](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Particles/Hair) is a very easy way to have objects scattered randomly on your ground plane. This can be very useful for creating litter in cities, rocks & sticks in woods, trees in forests, weeds in abandoned lots, etc:

[image]

---

### Step #1: Create your Objects

1. Add to your scene one of each type of object you want to have scattered on the ground. In this example, I'm using 3 objects:

   [image]
2. Each object's [*Origin Point*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects) is the point where the object will touch the ground plane. So, make sure to place the Origin Point accordingly. In this example, we'll move the Origin Point of each object to the mesh's bottom-most point:
   Select an object > *Edit* mode (<kbd>TAB</kbd>) > select all (<kbd>A</kbd>) > move the object up until it's *Origin* is at the base of the object:

   [image]
3. Now make all your objects a *Group* by selecting them all and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>
4. Then name your group something like "Object Group" in the *Tools* panel (<kbd>T</kbd>)

   [image]
5. Now rotate all the objects 90 degrees on the Y axis. **This is very important** because in hair particle systems, particles use the global +X axis as "up" for orienting the particle (or object, as in the case here):
   *Object Mode* > select object > <kbd>R</kbd> > <kbd>Y</kbd> > <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

   [image]
6. You can now move them off to the side or to a different [layer](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/Layers) -- **just don't rotate them.**

---

### Step #2: Make Your Particle System

1. Add a Hair particle system to your ground plane:
   Select ground plane > *Object Properties* window > *Particle System* tab > click *New* > set *Type* to *Hair*

   [image]
2. For the particle system, make the following settings:

   - Enable *Advanced*
     [image]
   - In the *Render* section, select *Group*, and set *Dupli Group* to your object group, and enable *Rotation*
     [image]
   - Enable the *Rotation* section, set *Initial Orientation* to *Normal*, and the *(Rotation) Random* to 1
     [image]
   - In the *Physics* section, adjust the *Size* of your objects, and if you want some of the objects to be random sizes then adjust *Random Size*
     [image]
   - Adjust the *Number* of objects in the *Emission* section
     [image]

   The result is a scattering of your objects over the ground:

   [image]

---

Comment: Is there any way that the objects in group can be replicated through particles(as you described), but no scaling is applied to those scattered objects (Scale of scattered objects shall be similar to the grouped objects) ?

Comment: Yes, if I remember correctly, in the “Render” section, do not enable “Scale” (so no checkmark in that box.)

Comment: Just tried you recomendation but no use :(......I believe it's Emission > hair length =1; Physics > Newtonian > Size=1. But, not sure.

Comment: If you can, disable Random Size. Maybe set it to zero?