# Is it possible to use a texture to control the size of particles?

Tags: particles

I'm trying to make a forest with a particle system, but I want a controlled variation in tree size. Is it possible to use a displacement texture or something similar to control the size of the particles?

Comment: [This method](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8927/is-there-a-way-to-procedurally-scatter-objects-on-the-ground-of-my-scene) also allows for controlling size of particles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add a texture to your emitter and in the influence panel of the texture choose **Size** for emitter particles or **Length** for hair particles.

[image]
[image]