# Is there a way to set particle size equal to a texture or vertex map?

Tags: particles

Is there a way I can set particle size equal to a texture map in Blender? I can't find any setting to do it in the particles tab. Maybe this is a feature that could be added to Blender?

Comment: There's a way with texture for Particle system, related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29221/is-it-possible-to-drive-the-length-of-hair-particles-via-texture-using-cycles. However you'll need to find appropriate coordinates for that texture.