# Can i weight paint a logo?

Tags: weight-painting, texture-painting, vertex-weights, dynamic-paint

Hi i woul like to paint my logo on a weighmap for my grass system but i cant figure out how to change the brush or use a texture like in texture paint mode. Is it nor possible? Should i draw the logo on hand?

Comment: Are you trying to vertex paint a plane?  You seem to be talking about texture painting but they you invoke weightmapping...

Comment: yes i try to paint a logo on a weigt map that controll my grass so the grass will grow on the plance exept in some places forming the logo.

Comment: What do you think is the best way to do this?

Comment: Unless you've got a special reason to use vertex weight, wouldn't it be easier to use an image  texture to control the length of the grass?

Comment: So it is not possible to change the weight paint brush or apply a texture?

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you can also use both procedural and image textures to drive the length of your grass:

**[Hair_Length_by_Image_Texture.blend](https://github.com/manujarvinen/Blends/raw/master/Hair_Length_by_Image_Texture.blend)**

[image]

More info **[here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/29252/8282)**.

Answer (score 1):

To transfer a texture to vertex weights, you can use a Vertex Weight Edit Modifier, which accepts a texture as a mask.

Personally, I find the current [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/weight_edit.html) unhelpful, and I haven't managed to reverse-engineer the logic of the modifier's fields from its behavior, so this answer isn't as complete as it should be.

[image]

The 'Logo Tex' texture in this example is a white out of black logo.
The 'Logo Group' vertex group is all the vertices of a subdivided plane, set to 0, initially.

The critical settings for this case appear to be a smooth or spherical falloff, and a value in the Add Threshold slightly above the Default Weight.

You can apply the modifier and take the result into Weight Paint to smooth, or make other alterations to it.

It would be great if in a comment or proper answer to this question, someone could explain exactly what the settings are doing, or point me in the direction of a tutorial that isn't actually about something else, or based on guesswork.