# Controlling particle size via texture with particle physics disabled?

Tags: particles

I want to be able to control the sizes of particles with a texture, but as I want the particles to be used as terrain, I want to disable Newtonian physics so that the particles remain stationary.

However, particle size seems to be unchangeable with particle physics set to "No":

[image: Particle size only being affected by texture when physics set to "Newtonian"]

Is there a way to get particle textures to work properly without Newtonian physics enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use the **Type** 'Emitter', choose '**Hair**' instead, where the particles rest on their places.

I assume you regulated the size of the particles like it is described here
[Is it possible to use a texture to control the size of particles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9158/is-it-possible-to-use-a-texture-to-control-the-size-of-particles)

I tried it and it worked (I used a Marble-texture). Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Worked after I changed the texture influence to "Length" instead of "Size".