# Particle system: assign random instance objects

Tags: particles

I have a particle system that's instancing an object but I want to randomize the objects that are instanced. In my case, it's a snow flurry, so I'm looking to randomize different snowflake shapes instead of having every particle be the same shape.

Any way to do this without having to set up multiple particle systems from the same emitter?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8927/is-there-a-way-to-procedurally-scatter-objects-on-the-ground-of-my-scene/8928#8928

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for. Took me a while to find it in 2.8 but it's listed in physics > render > render as > collection.Thank you so much!