# How would I go about simulating a flooded city?

Tags: fluid-simulation, effects

I want to visualize what it looked like if a big city was flooded due to sea level rise. I want it to look as realistic as it can, but I am still kind of a beginner. So how would I do this? Do I need to build the entire city in Blender? Or can I use drone footage of the city and animate on top of it?

Comment: Quite big appetizer for beginner. I don't think anyone would be able to answer your Question, since it covers huge amount of topics for you. Try to check Lazy Tutorials like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjnyapZ_P-g   , but even this one expect previous knowledge. Or even you search here you can't miss this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8545/how-can-i-quickly-generate-create-a-large-city-without-modeling-it-all-by-hand For fluid sim there is a lot of tutorials.

Comment: Essential is also camera angle,. From final and well planed storyboard you can think what can be cheated or fakes and so on ... Not everything ha ago be full 3d, matte-painting is still trendy even in Hollywood  production.